# youtube api loadPlaylist on big array of videoIDs

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I've been struggling with the IFrame API for the past few days trying to get it to load a large list of videoIDs.  I'm trying to load the playlist with around 380 songs.

Now I believe that I read somewhere that the max size for a playlist is suppose to be 200 videos. I've cut down the array to a size of around 200 videos and it still doesn't work. However, when I cut the size of the array down to around 145 the playlist will load no problem.

What is happening, and why am I seeing this kind of functionality? Am I creating the playlist improperly? Is there a better way to create the playlist and allow 380+ videos to be loaded through the playlist?

In my code I have the initial array of around 380 videos called arrayOfVideoIDs. I then create another array called videoIDs200 which is just the arrayOfVideoIDs array spliced down to a smaller array. I currently have the splice to cut out the first 145 videos. I then load this smaller array in the playlist because the bigger array will not load.

Here is my code, please help :) :

```js
//BUTTON ASSIGNMENTS:
$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
  console.log("pressed previousBtn");
  previousVideo();
});

$("#pauseBtn").click(function() {
  console.log("pressed pauseBtn");
  pauseVideo();
});

$("#playBtn").click(function() {
  console.log("pressed playBtn");
  playVideo();
});

$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
  console.log("pressed nextBtn");
  nextVideo();
});

var arrayOfVideoIDs = ['KD5fLb-WgBU', 'o1o92o5WmyQ', '2DnOnw18u5E', 'B2yLFcmZ51I', 'G0V9FvY6W7Q', '47YClVMlthI', 'WyvXaHseiP4', 'Wi2uU3kTQ24', 'o1o92o5WmyQ', 'vd1xC18qB3k', '436aaEOwG4g', '5rTcU_qc760', 'bQSi33FJZM4', 'AF3yXSJq8iM', 'LsRqHzZfc3Y', 'fmAnU6egxTE', 'lUo4Po6Vawg', 'ZoHF7oCWOmU', 'fUyF6xfzHMA', 'vWt-8RxpE3U', 'ciyniKSRIwo', 'WRtBwjt9cXo', 'c0ApHOhrHkw', 'wvzfOyW0ZMo', 'k1eVdaDTPeM', 'DwyABA9OiHY', 'xeQ31jQNAVI', 'Vf_WUSXiv00', 'pzAo3Hj15R4', 'qAzORs7VEFs', '6A7UMUaXIxI', 'nntGTK2Fhb0', 'PQZhN65vq9E', 'z2fFHfLkFow', '-Y0Abj01XJY', 'iApcWLG3neA', 'jYCCr1VsXLs', 'rpAC3l2_SDw', '5E-u-MVJcvU', '-B9NOnOGboc', '2Rxa4pNAnMY', '_x7KeDvNjEE', 'BB3OGwplrLo', 'Z4TwbrihsNw', 'BPzG12uXSwQ', 'BYDY_3BnoPk', 'S1g4Uoqhhc8', 'VmInLHzJxHs', 'q3LQzYSrirM', '-bWFDJlKhxQ', 'v1wpH0HJf-c', 'i_kF4zLNKio', 'nKhHzd64IhM', '-EuXIBb7xgQ', 'hJtNvBtL9rg', 'OtAfyTrIzeM', 'sWtS8vTahts', '27d138zhyZQ', 'EvU5fwkbQf0', '8y38Ftb9KBc', 'ff2lz6hnQRA', 'BN5dQvYGBdE', '3_-a9nVZYjk', '6366dxFf-Os', 'GQdR5th38-w', 'QjJhzkf4WbA', 'XPpkzX4CpOo', 'E-5E-LqJHno', 'Xqw4wo8vdY8', 'Sk9XYQMRiLY', 'Cw_o4nltIVc', 'Hf9rPrpP3GU', 'hCeZsWHg7vo', 'PG_D-JpGqsM', 'zF5uMvCGUCM', 'p_u3ql2gvBo', 'kcZMCMI24gs', '37RYC5aZlRo', 'aPxVSCfoYnU', 'Zovq8G3hcc0', 'vnT4w2s0OT4', 'NQv_bylC2Ic', 'yteXdnQQSUc', 'S1g4Uoqhhc8', 'GvS1Yf-ErZI', 'DW47_D8zGW0', 'ta9C7O5ULxU', '21YJcWdiNfI', 'wvWHhZgnjrc', 'rVeMiVU77wo', 'BsGnMpSVixg', 'YqeW9_5kURI', 'Xqw4wo8vdY8', '3_-a9nVZYjk', 'SNppM_-r6s4', 'LWizvjVHQBA', '2Q74TyTUrTo', 'Y7OCgi7rANc', '5Lnl_AOdcuw', 'nntGTK2Fhb0', 'E8pNta0mtw0', 'ta9C7O5ULxU', 'WinkoZiOYQc', 'BsGnMpSVixg', 'qAzORs7VEFs', '1x1wjGKHjBI', 'GCdwKhTtNNw', 'oCLek4aSpbo', 'hYru9VCXSl0', 'Gz2GVlQkn4Q', 'FfBKqaVk2Co', '_nW5AF0m9Zw', '5bfseWNmlds', 'dX3k_QDnzHE', 'uJ_1HMAGb4k', 'LLK4oaXUuLg', 'jlaeJ6k75cY', 'ukNOaKeUEQY', 'hZvFGEE26vE', 'Q5_47eLxb8o', 'dCCXq9QB-dQ', 'P2rT2vw9i_k', 'YWyHZNBz6FE', 'geKlJbCpEdw', 'L-rQZ6IGhCM', 'CxnaPa8ohmM', '88sTh9FVOjQ', 'atRKZIKBm7A', 'oAncODpky6E', 'GCdwKhTtNNw', 'Rfmg7NYzN6o', 'FkFilcTiKnM', '_L2vJEb6lVE', 'j5-yKhDd64s', 'HcVv9R1ZR84', '4EyZJXGVRO0', 'ybNvCJ_zPsY', 'mI2L7U5n0LI', '8y38Ftb9KBc', 'QtNJ_OOOJQQ', 'pFcYrqw9YwY', 'ZkAeootuf4w', 'E1qtnLLGjaI', 'XYgSHOWNE0M', 'bcQt_UVnwe8', 'z6ZDX-l4Xsg', 'CcZeTCahve0', '1612_Y7N9x4', 'K0jkjiSEfXY', 'bbEoRnaOIbs', 'SDTZ7iX4vTQ', 'MqI_O3kIFHM', 'Ijk4j-r7qPA', 'oMBMgxUw6YQ', 'PWgvGjAhvIw', 'jkaMiaRLgvY', 'ZxpMk3pvz44', 'VPRjCeoBqrI', 'vEHHh8IBhpY', 'P4qHQfbAkaQ', 'bgra1M1F90g', 'jbZ5d8I1oHI', 'jbZ5d8I1oHI', 'SeXBiXcEBkY', 'iBHNgV6_znU', 'YgSPaXgAdzE', 'mzJj5-lubeM', 'l1p_NHFd8jM', '3cqU1pFRqYE', '312Sb-2PovA', '0Uc3ZrmhDN4', 'PWgvGjAhvIw', 'EO8YRTG3y5w', 'VCkFSe3voRc', 'FFhs6_b8tzs', 'HAfFfqiYLp0', '3cqU1pFRqYE', 'nXr1YK3YdWQ', 'xLUVYGOOOKE', 'wRCPCNtViGA', 'JzIK5FaC38w', 'Qp6Coee-iJg', '8LbkxP_UCBQ', '_zPlr-o-YEQ', 'gomT8CJ0pg0', 'gkime9M4z34', 'Py2pZqyfhr0', '6PhkfhKqh3w', 'L2NhfzcVmBA', 'mp-IZEFqrG0', 'IxxstCcJlsc', 'zXbky7eU3qg', 'LL-gyhZVvx0', 'TGx0rApSk6w', 'oZzfZwbOyQM', 'YLCm9lP-3Uk', '6zwjuv53dgI', 'auw2bndbdbQ', '0mVck88W01I', 'JPIhUaONiLU', 'ISFUG005Flg', 'KTYD_kN7rPg', '6BbVTGidzk8', 'HhTWwtMfbH4', 'LV5_xj_yuhs', 'gFAhxdkwDxs', 'wvzfOyW0ZMo', 'ZxpMk3pvz44', 'Vd3D7aw4zns', '4Uc9bRYHlMs', 'jGow4nmYkkA', 'Wb5VOQexMBU', 'i-gyZ35074k', 'GO1ih209NlU', 'q8kUckZ15fE', 'ZlF-V1la8tE', 'J1R541QFXxc', 'I1Czsw7OPUI', '-m7e7tCn7Bk', '5mJ08-pyDLg', 'P-JRWEn_R1U', '_SvQ_qdVKTg', 'eYOMDtXCFcE', '2739ZWjgnT0', 'OOevVQwQ-LM', 'E1IoTvqMR5I', '2sBoWE-xJQk', 'akhmS1D2Ce4', '-tPEVDVuNc4', 'PEbJ4qLiMu0', 'pjgFYQMWtqo', 'PEbJ4qLiMu0', 'ixpTThi94tg', '_O6VE7erP2w', 'EAc4zHEDd7o', '-0oZNWif_jk', 'UDf1wFiOnwY', '_O6VE7erP2w', '5RNePy_awq0', '30BeqAiU_sA', '_uEKLAmqxWY', 'My2FRPA3Gf8', 'TrPuLBquyM0', 'DwEqTbaFVXU', 'CFwSE72ZuOc', 'tczpiOxjyC4', 'aXfneptTov4', 'Oo5T0VWsdBU', 'ZeaIvjoH1FY', 'uG_BBVLp3dA', 'PJGTG6ne5AY', 'ktvTqknDobU', 'M0FdMJW3r2M', 'IoT_S_kduEQ', 'iz9AHuv7qLY', 'uqMmhyAFApY', 'wg2yPkh8VDo', 'ZeaIvjoH1FY', 'CGOt8dZRsHk', 'JaAWdljhD5o', 'p74sRyhPNaU', '2cXDgFwE13g', 'WSlnlDzxpSE', 'enPWq0TfSFU', 'BYDKK95cpfM', 'pn1VGytzXus', 'xzXDSWz3Nbw', 'hCdgDxQbW_U', 'BmsbobsA7w8', 'XvF48Bb6nvI', 'R9PPYSkIWLU', 'YupMaBazaVM', '6Pf-AJbTCXM', 'Z8FarCnm1mE', 'W7FfCJb8JZQ', 'ZrH3vNfQcmU', 'bioAFbYfc54', 'BYDKK95cpfM', 'IVM7T8AN9EM', 't8p_Ewi7ddQ', 'g5Ehr5U7MPE', 'bWFbOheW07Y', 'NFnKgIptbq0', 'AVRkEcHP0kk', 'QsimPcAbM_w', 'OYws8biwOYc', 'ylqNUIKUdIE', 'cdbwN1goLGI', 'QtOwSRGBMG8', 'JdR557TvOLM', 'fskQpofUquk', 'ca3hhFfFH-k', '1o-Kvvpbg-A', 'Z8OGGxybgR4', 'K779kEdCuUA', 'eL0ukIqDt2I', 'VuX_zwX3jPg', 'lTx3G6h2xyA', '_NzZxLEyosE', 'BfWpIGMC-aI', 'WsKZd8Y5RvI', 'zRnDIXsGIyc', 'K1VLaXoRRdk', 'w2yv8aT0UFc', 'erywPdFfORE', 'FDYIdBZUl2Y', 'CMfrXXTvfd8', '6bSsmyG9PJE', '5OT2M1r-XyM', 'rFwrItEhW6k', 'PEbJ4qLiMu0', '7pKrVB5f2W0', 'CucdaMUku_E', 'pny7ibWhHG4', '0_B57fVyySo', '9V0fXx6DQp0', 'HAfFfqiYLp0', '3iUuWK0jgHk', 'aUduYknAGe8', 'VLKaD81wcD4', 'Imixg3jrJS8', 'tv_8NpBe4-Y', 'YXwYJyrKK5A', 'ub36ffWAqgQ', 'MmZexg8sxyk', '6hz8fuw5adc', 'DhjriEZYzc8', 'fWw66B9JFYo'];

var videoIDs200 = arrayOfVideoIDs.slice(0, 145);

$("#pressMe").click(function() {
  console.log(arrayOfVideoIDs);
  console.log(videoIDs200);
});

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  console.log('onYouTubeIframAPIReady()');

  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: '',
    playerVars: {
      'enablejsapi': 1,
      'modestbranding': 1,
      'playsinline': 0,
      'rel': 0,
      'autoplay': 1
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  console.log("onPlayerReady()")
  event.target.loadPlaylist(videoIDs200);
  //event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
    console.log("Player State: CUED");
  }

  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.CUED && event.data !== YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    console.log("Player State: CUED and not PLAYING");
    player.playVideo();
  }

  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    console.log("Player State: ENDED");
    playNext();
  }

  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    console.log("Player State: PLAYING");
  }

  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
    console.log("Player State: PAUSED");
  }

  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
    console.log("Player State: BUFFERING");
  }
}


// Loads and plays the next video
function nextVideo() {
  player.nextVideo();
}

// Loads the and plays the previous video
function previousVideo() {
  player.previousVideo();
}

// Plays video in playlist at specified index
function playVideoAt(index) {
  player.playVideoAt(index);
}

//PLAYBACK CONTROLS

// Plays the currently cued/loaded video
function playVideo() {
  player.playVideo();
}

// Pauses the currently playing video
function pauseVideo() {
  player.pauseVideo();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Real 8Tracks Scraper</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


  <!-- Include JQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Youtube IFrame API -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
  <div id="player"></div>
  <div id="player"></div>
  <button class="btn" id="pressMe">press me</button>
  <button class="btn" id="prevBtn">
    <<</button>
      <button class="btn" id="pauseBtn">||</button>
      <button class="btn" id="playBtn">|></button>
      <button class="btn" id="nextBtn">>></buton>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have seen the same issue. it looks like youtube just puts a limit on the playlist size. not documented anywhere as far as i can tell.

Comment: I wound up not using the load playlist function and resorted to keeping the array of video ids as my playlist and implemented a playlist controller that will iterate through this array of video ids.